# Colouring Excel cell with condition using DocumentFormat.OpenXml

Tags: spreadsheet

I would like to know if someone have worked on DocumentFormat.OpenXml as I have an issue with the colouring of sheet cell on condition using DocumentFormat.Spreadsheet.

Now I can create the colour for the 1st time but I need to open the same excel sheet and based on the condition I need to colour a particular cell. E.g. if cell D1 is yellow then D2 may be green or yellow.

e.g.

```
Name    IpAddress   Region  Details
Switch  10.1.1.1    EMEA    Based on Condition the cell would be coloured  
Switch  10.1.1.2    AMER    Based on Condition the cell would be coloured  
Switch  10.1.1.3    APAC    Based on Condition the cell would be coloured  
Switch  10.1.1.2    AMER    Based on Condition the cell would be coloured  
Switch  10.1.1.2    AMER    Based on Condition the cell would be coloured
```

I’m writing each row at a time and when I want to open existing excel sheet I would pass the value i.e. _valuecolour and based its value it would colour the particular cell along with the alignment of the other cells.

I have used the code below.

```
public static bool InsertRowExcel(string filepath, string _sb, string _switchinput)
        {
            int i = 0;
            string[] _arr = _switchinput.Split(',');
            bool bl = false;
            int k = 0;
            try
            {
                using (SpreadsheetDocument myDoc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filepath, true))
                {
                    //Get workbookpart
                    WorkbookPart workbookPart = myDoc.WorkbookPart;
                    WorkbookStylesPart stylePart = workbookPart.WorkbookStylesPart;
                    Row row = new Row();
                    //then access to the worksheet part
                    IEnumerable<WorksheetPart> worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts;
                    foreach (WorksheetPart WSP in worksheetPart)
                    {
                        //find sheet data
                        IEnumerable<SheetData> sheetData = WSP.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>();
                        // Iterate through every sheet inside Excel sheet
                        foreach (SheetData SD in sheetData)
                        {
                            IEnumerable<Row> rows = SD.Elements<Row>(); // Get the row IEnumerator
                            i = (rows.Count()); // Will give you the count of rows

                            do
                            {   row = new Row();
                                row.Append(
                                ConstructCell(_arr[0], CellValues.String),
                                ConstructCell(_arr[1], CellValues.String),
                                ConstructCell(_arr[2], CellValues.String),
                                ConstructCell(_sb, CellValues.String,2U)
                                );

                            }
                            while (k > 0);
                           /* HERE I NEED TO ADD STYLE TO THE CELL. */
                       }
                    }

                    bl = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                bl = false;

                throw ex;
            }
            return bl;
        }

private static Stylesheet GenerateStylesheet(bool _valuecolour)
        {
            Stylesheet styleSheet = null;
            Fills fills = new Fills();            
            if (_valuecolour)
            {

                fills = new Fills(
                    new Fill(new PatternFill() { PatternType = PatternValues.None }), // Index 0 - default
                    new Fill(new PatternFill() { PatternType = PatternValues.Gray125 }), // Index 1 - default
                     new Fill(new PatternFill(new ForegroundColor { Rgb = new HexBinaryValue() { Value = "FFFFFF00" } })
                     { PatternType = PatternValues.Solid })
               );
            }
            else
            {

                 fills = new Fills(
                   new Fill(new PatternFill() { PatternType = PatternValues.None }), // Index 0 - default
                   new Fill(new PatternFill() { PatternType = PatternValues.Gray125 }), // Index 1 - default
                   new Fill(new PatternFill(new ForegroundColor { Rgb = new HexBinaryValue() { Value = "008000" } })
                   { PatternType = PatternValues.Solid }) // Index 2 - body
              );
            }
            CellFormats cellFormats = new CellFormats(
                    new CellFormat(), // default
                    new CellFormat(new Alignment() { Horizontal = HorizontalAlignmentValues.Left, Vertical = VerticalAlignmentValues.Top, WrapText = true })
                    { FontId = 0, FillId = 0, BorderId = 1, ApplyAlignment = true },
new CellFormat(new Alignment() { Horizontal = HorizontalAlignmentValues.Left, Vertical = VerticalAlignmentValues.Top, WrapText = true }){ FontId = 1, FillId = 2, BorderId = 1, ApplyFill = true }); // header

            styleSheet = new Stylesheet(fills, cellFormats);            
            return styleSheet;
        }


private static Cell ConstructCell(string value, CellValues dataType,uint styleIndex = 0)
        {
            return new Cell()
            {
                CellValue = new CellValue(value),
                DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(dataType),
                StyleIndex = styleIndex
            };
        }
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: It is only a request from my side as i'm completely blocked.

Comment: Yeah, don't do it. If you read the whole of the link I've supplied, you'll understand why. The amount of begging and pleading we get here is exhausting.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion halfer. The only issue is how to retreive the cell and fill the background colour, rest I can manage can you help me in this regards

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code which works as expected

enter code here

```
#region ReadWriteExcel File
        public static bool ReadWriteExcel(string _sb, string _switchinput, bool _checkinitial)
        {
            string _str = string.Empty;
            bool _checkStatus = false;
            bool bl = false;
            String[] _arr;
            _arr = _switchinput.Split(',');
            int i = 0;
            string filepath = _directoryPath + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy") + ".xlsx";
            bl = (File.Exists(filepath) ? true : false);
            if (bl) // && _checkinitial
            {
                //_sb = string.Empty;
                //LogWrite("Just Before InsertRowExcel " + _switchinput);
                _checkStatus = InsertRowExcel(filepath, _sb.ToString(), _switchinput);
            }
            else
            {
                using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(filepath, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        WorkbookPart workbookPart = document.AddWorkbookPart();
                        workbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();

                        WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
                        WorkbookStylesPart stylePart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>();
                        worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet();

                        Sheets sheets = workbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());

                        Sheet sheet = new Sheet() { Id = workbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart), SheetId = 1, Name = "SAN Switch Health Check" };
                        sheets.Append(sheet);
                        stylePart.Stylesheet = GenerateStylesheetDefault();
                        stylePart.Stylesheet.Save();
                        workbookPart.Workbook.Save();
                        SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.AppendChild(new SheetData());
                        // Constructing header
                        Row row = new Row();

                        row.Append(
                            ConstructCell("Device_type", CellValues.String),
                            ConstructCell("Name", CellValues.String),
                            ConstructCell("IP Address", CellValues.String),
                            ConstructCell("Status", CellValues.String)
                          );

                        // Insert the header row to the Sheet Data
                        sheetData.AppendChild(row);

                        do
                        {
                            //for (int i = 0; i < _arr.Length - 1; i++)
                            //{
                            row = new Row();
                            row.Append(
                                ConstructCell(_arr[0], CellValues.String, 1U),
                                ConstructCell(_arr[1], CellValues.String, 1U),
                                ConstructCell(_arr[2], CellValues.String, 1U));//,
                                                                               //ConstructCell(_sb, CellValues.String,2U));
                                                                               //sheetData.AppendChild(row);
                        }
                        while (i > 0);

                        if (_sb != "Normal")
                        {
                            row.Append(
                              ConstructCell(_sb, CellValues.String, 2U));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            row.Append(
                            ConstructCell(_sb, CellValues.String, 3U));
                        }
                        sheetData.AppendChild(row);
                        //stylePart.Stylesheet.Save();
                        worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();

                        _checkStatus = true;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        _checkStatus = false;
                        //LogWrite(ex.StackTrace.ToString());
                        throw ex;
                    }
                    document.Close();
                    document.Dispose();
                }

            }
            return _checkStatus;
        }
        private static Cell ConstructCell(string value, CellValues dataType, uint styleIndex = 0)
        {
            return new Cell()
            {
                CellValue = new CellValue(value),
                DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(dataType),
                StyleIndex = styleIndex
            };
        }

        public static bool InsertRowExcel(string filepath, string _sb, string _switchinput)
        {
            // LogWrite("InsertRowExcel " + _switchinput);

            int i = 0; int k = 0; bool bl = false; string[] _arr = _switchinput.Split(',');

            using (SpreadsheetDocument myDoc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filepath, true))
            {

                //Get workbookpart

                WorkbookPart workbookPart = myDoc.WorkbookPart;

                WorkbookStylesPart stylePart = workbookPart.WorkbookStylesPart;
                Row row = new Row();
                stylePart.Stylesheet = GenerateStylesheetDefault();
                stylePart.Stylesheet.Save();
                //then access to the worksheet part

                IEnumerable<WorksheetPart> worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts;

                foreach (WorksheetPart WSP in worksheetPart)
                {//find sheet data
                    SheetData sheetData = WSP.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First();


                    IEnumerable<Row> rows = sheetData.Elements<Row>(); // Get the row IEnumerator
                    i = (rows.Count()); // Will give you the count of rows                      
                                        /* HERE I NEED TO ADD STYLE TO THE CELL on condition. */
                    do
                    {
                        row = new Row();
                        row.Append(
                        ConstructCell(_arr[0], CellValues.String),
                        ConstructCell(_arr[1], CellValues.String),
                        ConstructCell(_arr[2], CellValues.String)
                        );
                        if (_sb != "Normal")
                        {
                            row.Append(
                              ConstructCell(_sb, CellValues.String, 2U));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            row.Append(
                            ConstructCell(_sb, CellValues.String, 3U));
                        }

                        sheetData.Append(row);
                    } while (k > 0);
                }
                bl = true;
                myDoc.Close();
                myDoc.Dispose();
            }

            return bl;
        }
        public static Stylesheet GenerateStylesheetDefault()
        {
            Stylesheet stylesheet1 = new Stylesheet();
            Fonts fonts = new Fonts(
                new Font(
                    new FontSize() { Val = 11D },
                    new Color() { Theme = (UInt32Value)1U },
                     new FontName() { Val = "Calibri" },
                     new FontFamilyNumbering() { Val = 2 },
                     new FontScheme() { Val = FontSchemeValues.Minor }
                    )
                );

            Borders borders = new Borders(
                new Border(
                    new LeftBorder(),
                    new RightBorder(),
                    new TopBorder(),
                    new BottomBorder(),
                    new DiagonalBorder())
                );
            Fills fills = new Fills();

            fills = new Fills(
                new Fill(
                    new PatternFill() { PatternType = PatternValues.None }), //0
                new Fill(
                    new PatternFill() { PatternType = PatternValues.Gray125 }),//1
                new Fill(
                    new PatternFill(
                        new ForegroundColor { Rgb = new HexBinaryValue() { Value = "FFFFFF00" } }) //2 -yellow
                    { PatternType = PatternValues.Solid }),
                new Fill(
                    new PatternFill(
                        new ForegroundColor { Rgb = new HexBinaryValue() { Value = "FF008000" } })// 3 -green
                    { PatternType = PatternValues.Solid })
                );

            CellStyleFormats cellStyleFormats = new CellStyleFormats(
                new CellFormat() { NumberFormatId = (UInt32Value)0U, FontId = (UInt32Value)0U, FillId = (UInt32Value)0U, BorderId = (UInt32Value)0U }
                );

            CellFormats cellFormats = new CellFormats(
                new CellFormat() { NumberFormatId = (UInt32Value)0U, FontId = (UInt32Value)0U, FillId = (UInt32Value)0U, BorderId = (UInt32Value)0U, FormatId = (UInt32Value)0U },
                 new CellFormat(
                     new Alignment() { Horizontal = HorizontalAlignmentValues.Left, Vertical = VerticalAlignmentValues.Top, WrapText = true })
                 { FontId = 0, FillId = 0, BorderId = 0, ApplyAlignment = true },
                 new CellFormat(
                     new Alignment() { Horizontal = HorizontalAlignmentValues.Left, Vertical = VerticalAlignmentValues.Top, WrapText = true })
                 { FontId = 0, FillId = 2, BorderId = 0, ApplyFill = true },
                new CellFormat(
                     new Alignment() { Horizontal = HorizontalAlignmentValues.Left, Vertical = VerticalAlignmentValues.Top, WrapText = true })
                { FontId = 0, FillId = 3, BorderId = 0, ApplyFill = true }
                );

            stylesheet1.Append(fonts);
            stylesheet1.Append(fills);
            stylesheet1.Append(borders);
            stylesheet1.Append(cellStyleFormats);
            stylesheet1.Append(cellFormats);
            return stylesheet1;
        }
        #endregion
```